# How to completely delete element from Javascript array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using this code to iterate over an array and delete the element if it contains no itemsToPost.

```
  rssFeeds.forEach(function(feed, index, array){
    if(feed.itemsToPost.length == 0){
      delete rssFeeds[index]
    }
  });
```

However, the array that I receive from this, assuming that all elements are deleted looks like:

```
[ ,  ]
```

And when I run this against Lodash's method to test if an array is empty.

```
console.log(_.isEmpty(array))) // returns 'false'
```

How can I completely delete these elements such that the array is truly empty?

Update:

I've found a solution using Array.prototype.filter as was suggested, such as:

```
  function hasNewItems(array) {
    return array.itemsToPost.length > 0;
  }

  var newArray = rssFeeds.filter(hasNewItems)
  console.log(newArray); // returns []
```

It isn't necessarily deleting the array but it has the desired effect.

Comment: have a look at `Array.prototype.filter`

Answer (score 2):

`delete` is not the correct way to remove element from array, you should use `rssFeeds.splice(index, 1)` instead.

Comment: This is correct in general, but can cause failures in a loop like in the question.